# incorrect csv file name after download from controller

Tags: php, csv, symfony, serialization, response

1. What needs to be changed so that the name of the file after downloading is the same as I indicated
2. Why the file type is not detected on Windows and Linux. (on macos the extension is defined)

I do not save the file on the server, but I generate data on the fly and send it to the new Response()
After downloading, the file does not have the name that I want, it also does not show the file extension on Windows

```
    public function download(Request $request): Response
    {
        $array = [];

       /// filling the array

        $serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()], [new CsvEncoder()]);
        $csv = $serializer->encode($array, 'csv', [CsvEncoder::DELIMITER_KEY => ';', CsvEncoder::OUTPUT_UTF8_BOM_KEY => true]);

        $response = new Response($csv);
        $disposition = HeaderUtils::makeDisposition(HeaderUtils::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, "desiredFilename.csv");
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $disposition);

        return $response;
    }
```

file name after downloading like **e9ddc45c-f3b6-404d-8251-ee51bc488c6e.csv**

Comment: `var_dump($disposition)` gives what? What do the headers come out as?

Comment: @user3783243 ```string(37) "attachment; filename=desiredFilename.csv"```

Answer (score 0):

regarding [The MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#as_a_header_for_a_multipart_body) you need to include your filename in the **double quotations** `filename="desiredFilename.csv"` .

I think maybe you have to wrap the file name into it:

```
        $disposition = HeaderUtils::makeDisposition(HeaderUtils::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, '"desiredFilename.csv"');
```

FYI: I have seen the Symphony Docs and it's example is like what you have provided.

Comment: unfortunately, this option did not work either

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$response->header->set('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="desiredFilename.csv"');
```

I think this link can be useful: [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html)

Enjoy !

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.